# Moving messages from `content.js` to App.js in react-create-app when creating google-chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, create-react-app

I'm using the `react-create-app` library to create the google-chrome-extension. It tries to send a message from the file `content.js` to `App.js` and display it as an alert and in console.log. I have no mistakes. No alert appears and nothing is displayed in console.log. Someone could advise you. The extension starts normally.

**Structure project**

```
   project
        build
        node_modules
        public
            /assets
        content.js
        favicon.ico
        index.html
        manifest.json
        src
            App.js
        .gitignore
        package.json
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "chrome extension",
  "description": "Chrome extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["content.js"],
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Open the popup"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon-128.png",
    "48": "assets/icon-128.png",
    "128": "assets/icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**content.js**

```
/*global chrome*/
var timer = 0;
var si = setInterval(() => {
  try {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
      {
        data: 'Hello popup, how are you'
      },
      function(response) {
        console.dir(response);
      }
    );
    timer++;
    if (timer === 5) {
      clearInterval(si);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // debugger;
    console.log(error);
  }
}, 2000);
```

**App.js**

```
/*global chrome*/
import * as React from 'react';
import Form from './components/form/Form';

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  alert('I am popup!');
  console.log('I am popup');
  sendResponse({
    data: 'I am fine, thank you. How is life in the background?'
  });
});

function App() {
  return <Form />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The popup is a separate page which runs only when shown (just like any other normal page) so it can't listen to messages when it's not shown. You'll need a background script - it'll always listen, but it's hidden so you'll want to change the way you're presenting the info, like maybe use a notification. Also, your manifest's content_scripts section is invalid as it has a trailing comma and missing `"matches"` but I guess it's just a bad copypaste.

Comment: Did you find the solution? @wOxxOm I did not understand what your saying. I already have [background.js](https://github.com/kasir-barati/open-ai-summaries/blob/11960c9391338504b85fa06cde04a7bd04e7ceb7/apps/chrome/public/background.js) but IDK how to listen to it [here](https://github.com/kasir-barati/open-ai-summaries/blob/11960c9391338504b85fa06cde04a7bd04e7ceb7/apps/chrome/src/components/CreateSummary/CreateSummary.component.tsx)